How to show a delayed real-time video from camera using flutter and camera package
I would like to show a video stream coming from the camera like the CameraPreview widget in the 'camera' package, but then with a (configurable) delay (up to 60 seconds); so basically an 'almost' live stream of the camera input, storing it temporarily in memory and then display it after 10, 20, 30, ... seconds.
I've looked at the CameraPreview widget itself and tried to find a way to branch a video stream from there, but could not find a handle to do so.
I also looked at the 'StartImageStream' function, that provides a callback to receive the frames of the stream, but I encounter two issues there:

First I'm not sure how to transform these frames into a stream to display on screen; I could use some help there
Second, after reading some articles and questions on this function, I fear that transforming these frames will be very (too much) time consuming and degrade video quality dramatically.

Can anybody tell me if my requirement is feasible, and if so I should go forward with 'StartImageStream', or that I should look for another approach?
[Update June 5th] Sofar I succeeded, with the help of some routines found online, to transform the image that is returned in the callback of StartImageStream to an image on screen (via a YUV to RGB conversion, and a display via a RawImage widget); basically my own implementation of the CameraPreview Widget. When run on my Samsung S10 I noticed the following:
When image transformation is turned off, and I show the original CameraPreview Widget, the framerate of the frames received by StartImageStream is about 28 fps. When I transform (via library in C) and show that image, the fps received drops to about 18, and the fps actually shown to about 10 fps. When I transform internally in Dart it's getting worse: about 9 fps received and 5 shown (ResolutionPreset set to high).

So first of all, image processing/transformation is heavy on the CPU and has a major impact on the number of frames that are sent to my StartImageStream callback, besides the fact that the processing itself makes me lose half of those frames again to be shown on screen. I would have to test further if this is a major issue on more recent devices.
Second, since the framerate sent to the callback is unpredictable, storing them in a buffer and showing them after a configurable delay will become difficult, since I would have to adapt the playback rate of that buffer to the fps received.

So my original question still stands, any  advice on how to proceed with my original requirement - the configurable delay; Do you think the camera plugin could be the way forward or should I start looking at a separate implementation for Android and iOS (or maybe go for a feature request with the makers of the plugin)?
